# How replace mouse events with Multipoint events

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mouseevent, multipoint

I have a WPF application that uses one -ordinary- mouse but I wanna allow multi user with multi mouse to use it.

I installed Microsoft Multipoint Sdk and configured it.

But How I can use Sdk events instead of user32.dll events?

Comment: Is it still being maintained?  [The last MSDN SDK blog entry was 5 years ago](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/multipoint/).  Check it out maybe there is something there

Comment: Do you have alternative? @MickyDuncan

Comment: No sorry.  I was not even aware that Windows could do such a thing until now

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need that.

Look into the MouseEventArgs. They all have a MouseDevice property to see which mouse caused the event.